# bitcoind -zmqpubhashtx causes empty raw file

Tags: zeromq

I call:

bitcoind -zmqpubrawtx=ipc:///tmp/bitcoind.tx.raw

or even call:

bitcoind -zmqpubhashtx=tcp://127.0.0.1:9050 -
zmqpubrawtx=ipc:///tmp/bitcoind.tx.raw

where 9050 is port from bicoin config.
File /tmp/bitcoind.tx.raw is empty i has lenght=0
How can I dump transactions?
I read, this file is websocket and I must subscribe to it:

```
Client side, then, the ZeroMQ subscriber socket must have the ZMQ_SUBSCRIBE 
option set to one or either of these prefixes (for instance, just hash); 
without doing so will result in no messages arriving. Please see 
contrib/zmq/zmq_sub.py for a working example."
```

How can I read it programically?
I try create c++ program from Python sources and https://github.com/plq/zmq.git

## include

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>

#include "zmq.hpp"

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

void recv_multipart(zmq::socket_t &socket) {
    int64_t more=-1;
    size_t more_size = sizeof (more);
    while(more) {
        zmq::message_t response;
        socket.recv(&response);

        std::string response_str((const char *)response.data(),
                                                             response.size());
        cout << response_str << endl;

        socket.getsockopt(ZMQ_RCVMORE, &more, &more_size);
    }
}


int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    zmq::context_t context(1);
    zmq::socket_t socket(context, ZMQ_SUB);
    socket.setsockopt(ZMQ_SUBSCRIBE, "hashblock");
    socket.setsockopt(ZMQ_SUBSCRIBE, "hashtx");
    socket.setsockopt(ZMQ_SUBSCRIBE, "rawblock");
    socket.setsockopt(ZMQ_SUBSCRIBE, "rawtx");
    //socket.connect(/*argv[2]*/"ipc:///tmp/bitcoind.tx.raw");
    socket.connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:28332");

    size_t arg_len= std::strlen("Unknown");
    zmq::message_t message(arg_len);
    std::memcpy(message.data(), "Unknown", arg_len);
    socket.send(message);        
    recv_multipart(socket);        
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can I use https://github.com/zaphoyd/websocketpp ?

Comment: It is a ZMQ socket. It is not a Websocket. Socket here refers to the old UNIX concept of a bidirectional interprocess pipe represented. ZMQ is a particular network protocol for publishing/subscribing to events.

Comment: soc=socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0); ? , sai.sin_family=PF_INET;
sai.sin_port=port; ?//how subscribe and read it? I need source code

Comment: You need libzmq.

Comment: I have compiled https://github.com/plq/zmq and this say: zmq <SOCKET_TYPE> <URI> <MSG>; how is SOCKET_TYPE,URI and MSG for this case?

Comment: zmq REQ ipc:///tmp/bitcoind.tx.raw ZMQ_SUBSCRIBE nor
zmq REQ tcp://127.0.0.1:28332 ZMQ_SUBSCRIBE nothing gets

Comment: That shell wrapper does not support SUBSCRIBE sockets.

Comment: I used Bitcoin Python example: sudo apt-get install python-zmq / 
python zmq_sub.py; but in this case program waits and no message to console

Answer (score 1):

First ensure, that is 28332 port used: -zmqpubhashtx=tcp://127.0.0.1:28332 bitcoind parameter, next call python zmq_sub.py. This should work